# How to fix non-greedy regular expression

Tags: python, regex

```
word = "\W*?[^,\t ]*?\W*?"
quotedSelectedWord = "\W*?\"(.*?)\"\W*?"
leftCurlyBrace = "\W*?\{\W*?"
rightCurlyBrace = "\W*?\}\W*?"
expression = leftCurlyBrace + word + "," + quotedSelectedWord

p = re.compile(expression)

for line in sourceFileList:
    line = line.strip()
    if (p.match(line)):         
        temp1 = p.sub(r"\1", line);
        print "temp1 = " + temp1 + "\n"
```

If the first line is (no actual single quotes):
'{_blah_blah, "blah-blah", "blah blah blah", false, false, {_blah}, ""},'

why is temp1 = 'blah-blah, "blah blah blah", false, false},'?

I thought it would be equivalent to the first "group" enclosed in parentheses, which I thought would be 'blah-blah'.

Comment: Just testing the catted regex `\W*?\{\W*?\W*?[^,\t ]*?\W*?,\W*?\"(.*?)\"\W*?` I get `{_blah_blah, "blah-blah"` whole match and `blah-blah` in capture group 1.

Comment: Try replace with $1.

Comment: First match lookes like it was replaced with `\1`, second match looks like replaced with `""` nothing. So sub is probably a global replace, but your regex won't match the entire line, so only parts will be replaced.

Comment: Sorry, so did you get this to work? When you say "first match" are you referring to \1 and when you say second match are you referring to \2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regular expression finds the pattern not once but twice.

The first one it finds is:

```
{_blah_blah, "blah-blah"
```

In which case `group(1)` (the part you put in parentheses above) is `blah-blah`, as you determined, which it uses to replace the first part of the string.

But it finds the pattern here too:

```
, {_blah}, ""
```

Here `group(1)`, which is still looking for `.*?`, is an empty string. So it replaces that part of the string with nothing, effectively removing it.

[This site](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/python/index.html) helped me sort this out.

Here's a [site](http://pythex.org) that shows both of these matches being found:

And a [link](http://pythex.org/?regex=%5CW*%3F%5C%7B%5CW*%3F%5CW*%3F%5B%5E%2C%5Ct%20%5D*%3F%5CW*%3F%2C%5CW*%3F%5C%22(.*%3F)%5C%22%5CW*%3F&test_string=%7B_blah_blah%2C%20%22blah-blah%22%2C%20%22blah%20blah%20blah%22%2C%20false%2C%20false%2C%20%7B_blah%7D%2C%20%22%22%7D%2C&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0) to it with the regex in place.

[image]

## Update

This website is even more helpful in parsing the regex: http://regex101.com/#python

At this site, enter the regular expression. An important point is to enter the `g` modifier to the right of it to get all the matches. Next enter the Test string, and Substitution of `\1`. It already shows you the matches and substitutions. So that's good. Now on the left click "regex debugger".

[image]

If you expand this section you'll be able to see exactly how it found the 2 matches:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The  [python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) states for `re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)`

> Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost non-overlapping occurrences of pattern in string by the replacement repl.

If we rewrite the for loop a bit:

```
for line in sourceFileList:
    line = line.strip()
    match = p.match(line)
    if (match):
        print "whole match = " + match.group()
        print "first group = " + match.group(1)
        temp1 = p.sub(r"\1", line)
        print "temp1 = " + temp1 + "\n"
```

we get the output:

```
whole match = {_blah_blah, "blah-blah"
first group = blah-blah
temp1 = blah-blah, "blah blah blah", false, false},
```

So this means that `{_blah_blah, "blah-blah"` will be replaced by `blah-blah` in your original string which still contains `, "blah blah blah", false, false, {_blah}, ""},` at the end.

If you just want to get the first capture group you can use `group(1)` as demonstrated above.

**Edit**:

As pointed out by the answer of twasbrillig, there are two replacements. If `re.sub` is called with `count = 0` or omitting the count parameter all occurrences of pattern are replaced and not only the first one.

---

Side note: I recommend to use raw strings in your patterns:

```
word = r"\W*?[^,\t ]*?\W*?"
```

Comment: But this doesn't explain why the end of the string: ` {_blah}, ""},` got removed, which is part of the OP's question.